# Finding an observation's value given values for other variables

Tags: search, stata

A simplified version of my data would look like:

```
Own_Name    Own_Position    Year    Boss_Name    Boss_Position
John        Director        2017    Tess         Managing Director
Tess        Lead Director   2017    Jim          CEO
John        Lead Director   2018    Jim          CEO
Tess        CFO             2018    Jim          CEO
```

All data concerning `Own_Name`, `Own_Position` and `Year` is present (so Jim and any others would get their own rows with `Own_Name` and `Boss_Name` etc.), but there are many entries where the `Boss_Position (but not`Boss_Name`) is missing.

Thus, I'm trying to find what the `Boss_Position` will be, given the `Boss_Name` and `Year`. I can do this if I need to pull just one observation (just keep the relevant data where `Own_Name` matches `Boss_Name` and `Year` matches, and use the corresponding `Own_Position`), but I am not sure what the best way to do this would be where I'm looping through all the missing observations for `Boss_Name`, since using `keep` would seem to be very destructive and time consuming.

Ideally, the code would look something like

```
replace Boss_Position = Own_Position[YearNameMatcher(Boss_Name  Year)] if missing(Boss_Position)
```

where `YearNameMatcher` is the function that does what I'm asking for, but I am not sure how to best proceed.

I'm also new to Stata, so I may not be aware of more obvious solutions, though I have tried searching without success.

Comment: See `help dataex` in an up-to-date Stata, or failing that install with `ssc install dataex`, to see a way to give people example data that they can use directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to generate a separate and temporary dataset with the unique values of variables `Boss_Name-Year` and then `merge` this dataset with the original data. You can try this code with your data:

```
snapshot save

keep if Boss_Position!=""
drop Own*
duplicates drop Year Boss_name, force
tempfile boss
save `boss'

snapshot restore 1

drop Boss_Position

merge m:1 Boss_Name Year using `boss'

snapshot erase _all
```

This code supposes that the paired values `Boss_name` and `Year` are unique. With this approach you don't need to loop through all the missing observations.

Comment: Helpful. Elsewhere you can find recommendation of the term "distinct" rather than "unique".  See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042 esp. p.558.